# Metadata of Amazon S3 object not getting updated while making PUT request on API using Postman

Tags: amazon-s3, postman, metadata, api-gateway

I am following this documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/) to upload S3 object using API gateway, with no Lambda in between. This works using Postman! The object gets uploaded, but the user-defined metadata is not been reflected in the object.

I am trying to add user-defined metadata to headers, but that seems to be not working. I also tried to add "x-amz-meta-{key}": "{value}" in the form-data field of the body, and that did not work as well. Any recommended solution? Thanks in advance!

[image: Using headers on postman]

[image: Adding metadata using form-data]

Comment: From the doc,  "When uploading an object, you can also assign metadata to the object. You provide this optional information as a name-value (key-value) pair when you send a PUT or POST request to create the object. When you upload objects using the REST API, the optional user-defined metadata names must begin with "x-amz-meta-" to distinguish them from other HTTP headers. When you retrieve the object using the REST API, this prefix is returned.", see last line, how are u verifying metadata not define?  Using HeadObject ?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html

Answer (score 0):

to Add metadata in **PUT/POST** request Created by **API Gateway**, you need to do the following:

1. Go to your API Method PUT/POST *Method Request*
2. Choose *HTTP Request Headers* then *Add Header* **x-amz-meta-{YOUR-METADATA-NAME}**
3. Go to your API Method PUT/POST *Integration Request*
4. Choose *HTTP Headers* then you will find your created Header in step 2 as Name (if not then create it) then in *Mapped from* Tab write
   **method.request.header.x-amz-meta-{YOUR-METADATA-NAME}**
5. Deploy then send put request with header key as **x-amz-meta-{YOUR-METADATA-NAME}** and add your value then
   visit s3 object you created then choose Edit Metadata then you find
   the added metadata

to Get Metadata with **GET** request Created by **API Gateway** beside the object in response headers, you need to do the following:

1. Go to your API *Method Response* then unfold right Arrow located on the left of 200.
2. choose *Add Header* on Response Headers for 200 then Add **x-amz-meta-{YOUR-METADATA-NAME}**
3. Go to your API Method *Integration Response*
4. unfold *Header Mappings* then you will find Response Header you created in previous step (if not then create it) then Add **integration.response.header.x-amz-meta-{YOUR-METADATA-NAME}** in *Mapping value* tab
5. Deploy then test it using Postman then you find metadata in *response headers*

have a good luck.